# Unrecognized credential type external_account when using workload identity federation in C# for Google ReCaptcha Enterprise

Tags: c#, azure, google-cloud-platform, recaptcha-enterprise

I am trying to setup Google ReCaptcha Enterprise in my API hosted in Azure. The API is responsible for creating assessments for the tokens that are sent from my frontend.

I have followed the steps [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/configuring-workload-identity-federation) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/using-workload-identity-federation) to setup workload identity federation so that I can use an Azure Managed Identity to impersonate my Google Cloud Service Account, but I get the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Error reading credential file from location clientLibraryConfig-myprojectgooglerecaptcha.json: Error creating credential from JSON or JSON parameters. Unrecognized credential type external_account.
Please check the value of the Environment Variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Error creating credential from JSON or JSON parameters. Unrecognized credential type external_account.
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.CreateDefaultCredentialFromParameters(JsonCredentialParameters credentialParameters)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.CreateDefaultCredentialFromStreamAsync(Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.CreateDefaultCredentialFromFileAsync(String credentialPath, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.CreateDefaultCredentialAsync()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.CreateDefaultCredentialAsync()
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.DefaultChannelCredentialsCache.<.ctor>b__5_1()
   at Google.Api.Gax.TaskExtensions.WaitWithUnwrappedExceptions(Task task)
   at Google.Api.Gax.TaskExtensions.ResultWithUnwrappedExceptions[T](Task`1 task)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.DefaultChannelCredentialsCache.GetCredentials()
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ChannelPool.GetChannel(GrpcAdapter grpcAdapter, String endpoint, GrpcChannelOptions channelOptions)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ClientBuilderBase`1.CreateCallInvoker()
   at Google.Cloud.RecaptchaEnterprise.V1.RecaptchaEnterpriseServiceClientBuilder.BuildImpl()
   at Google.Cloud.RecaptchaEnterprise.V1.RecaptchaEnterpriseServiceClientBuilder.Build()
   at Google.Cloud.RecaptchaEnterprise.V1.RecaptchaEnterpriseServiceClient.Create()
```

The exception happens when trying to create the service client:

```cs
var client = Google.Cloud.RecaptchaEnterprise.V1.RecaptchaEnterpriseServiceClient.Create();
```

The file that the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable points to look like this and was downloaded by following [these steps](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/using-workload-identity-federation#generate-automatic):

```json
{
  "type": "external_account",
  "audience": "//iam.googleapis.com/projects/<project id omitted>/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/myproject/providers/myprojectgooglerecaptcha",
  "subject_token_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:jwt",
  "token_url": "https://sts.googleapis.com/v1/token",
  "service_account_impersonation_url": "https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/projects/-/serviceAccounts/myproject@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com:generateAccessToken",
  "credential_source": {
    "url": "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=api://<Azure App Registration Client ID omitted>",
    "headers": {
      "Metadata": "True"
    },
    "format": {
      "type": "json",
      "subject_token_field_name": "access_token"
    }
  }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or does `RecaptchaEnterpriseServiceClient` not support workload identity federation?

Comment: The library you are using does not support the credential type **external_account**. I am not sure what the status is. Open an Issue Tracker feature request here: https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/5926547

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley. Do you know if there is a workaround in C# like by manually creating the credential object before creating the service client or by using another library?

Comment: I do not have an example in C# to recommend. How well do you understand tokens in Azure and GCP? The process is fairly easy. Request an Azure token (Azure), exchange for a federated token (Google STS), and then exchange for an access token (Google IAM). Most Google libraries accept an access token in the credentials class. The endpoints to call are listed in your questions JSON.

Comment: I would suggest subscribing to this issue: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/2033 - I'm not an expert, but I believe the recent work on Workflow Identity Federation will enable this scenario; I'm hopeful that we're nearly ready to release it.